# What is the best way to set up multiple public IP's

Tags: networking, router

I work for an IT company based in the US from home here in the UK. They currently have more available work in other departments, however they have told me that I will need a different public IP for each department. I am interested in working for 3 other departments, so I will need 3 new public IP's.

I am currently with virgin media fibre optic, so would I need to sign up with 3 new ISP's? So I could have virgin media fibre optic, sky fibre optic, bt broadband (phoneline) and talktalk (phoneline)

This is obviously going to cost me more, is there any other way I could achieve this? Maybe buy 3 new routers?

Comment: Off topic, but you need to question the ridiculous requirement.

Comment: I already know the reason for the requirement; up till now they only allowed each person to work in only one department, however now they have been taken over by a bigger company and have changed that policy, but they have not removed that filter/block from their systems yet. I was advised I could either wait till November until they update the system or instead of waiting work from a different IP. I know it sounds very dodgy but it's not :) A friend of mine works from his house then drives to his mother's to complete work for the other department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hey have told me that I will need a different public IP for each department. I am interested in working for 3 other departments, so I will need 3 new public IP's

This is off-topic for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but I will respond...

Most providers will allow you to purchase more IP addresses from them for a modest price.  In the US, I can buy them for about $15/additional address.

Another alternative is to find a virtual server hosting solution that allows you GUI console access over IP, as well as a dedicated virtual server IP address.  If you go this route, you use the virtual server's IP address for your VPN connection, and drive the VPN session from the GUI console.